# Can I parameterize background for a specific scenario in Cucumber

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bdd, cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

I have two scenarios which uses common credentials but second scenario needs to be run for 2 more credentials.

Is there any way through which I can pass parameterise background to achieve this?

For instance,
Background:

```
When A "<User Role>" logs in

Then User lands on a particular page

Scenario Outline: Test with single credential

    When user clicks on open button

    Then the page is displayed

    

    Examples: 

    |User Role|

    |Admin123         |
```

.
.
.
.

Scenario Outline: Test with multiple credential

```
When user clicks on open button

Then the page is displayed

And welcome note is displayed

Examples:

    |User Role|

    |Admin123         |

    |User1                 |

    |User2                      |
```

I want scenario 1 to run once with only Admin123 and scenario 2 thrice with the cred mentioned in examples

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use data from Examples in the background steps. The background steps are executed before each scenario, and they are intended to set up the initial state of the system under test. The data for background steps should be predefined and should not change for each scenario.

On the other hand, the `Examples` section is used to generate multiple scenarios with different input data. The input data is passed to the scenario steps through placeholders, which are replaced with actual values from the `Examples` table.

https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background

If you need to use data from Examples in your background steps, you should move the steps to your scenario itself.

```
 Scenario Outline: Test with single credential
    When A "<User Role>" logs in
    Then User lands on a particular page
    When user clicks on open button
    Then the page is displayed
    
    Examples:
      | User Role |
      | Admin123  |
```